# Include all PHP files from a directory except one 'index.php'

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code that scans a directory and sub folders and lists all the PHP files in iframes.
I want to include all the PHP files from the directory except one, any instance of 'index.php'.

I've tried adding:

```
 if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'index.php')
```

But it doesn't work.
Here's the full code:

```
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');

foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $cur) {
$file_info = pathinfo($filename);

if($file_info['extension'] === 'php') {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'index.php')

    echo 
  "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=1 src='$filename'></iframe>";
}
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `$file` defined? When developing, turn on all error reporting to catch mistakes like this easily.

Comment: hey dave, what are you trying to do? this code doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing it the iteratorish way, you might as well also use a filtering iterator. [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/RegexIterator) in particular can be useful, and avoid a few if checks in your case.

```
 $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');
 $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) 
 $iterator = new RegexIterator($iterator, "~(?<![/\\\\]index)\.php$~");
 foreach ($iterator as $filename=>$cur) {
     print "$filename<br>";
 }
```

I think testing for `.` and `..` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I'm still struggling to implement this (getting fatal errors!) - any further advice/pointers would be appreciated...

Comment: Can't give any advise on such vague descriptions.

Comment: I'm getting the following error message: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'An instance of RecursiveIterator or IteratorAggregate creating it is required'

Comment: Try wrapping the first in a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` again.

Comment: I didn't remove that - do you think that maybe the problem. Sorry I'm up against it now and panicking which really isn't helping! I have: 'code' <?php
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('4mg_work/');
$iterator = new RegexIterator($iterator, "~(?<![/\\\\]index)\.php$~");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $cur) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($filename);
 
    if($file_info['extension'] === 'php') {


        echo 
      "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=0 src='$filename'></iframe>";
    }
}

?> 'code'

Comment: You should wrap the *first* iterator, not the second.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow - you can tell this is the first time I've done anything in PHP! Is there some sort of conflict between them?

Comment: YOU RULE! - you've prevented a grown man weeping!! Really appreciate your help. Just a note for anyone else - there's a semi-colon missing at the end of the 2nd line. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You did not assign `$file`. It's always `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace `$filename` by `$file` everywhere and that should work:

```
<?php
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('work/');

foreach( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $file => $cur) {
$file_info = pathinfo($file);

if($file_info['extension'] === 'php') {
    if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file != 'index.php')

    echo 
  "<iframe width=420 height=150 frameborder=1 src='$file'></iframe>";
}
}

?>
```

I don't know what `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator` are though and their syntax seems strange.